# document is not a member of WindowBase

Tags: dart

I'am updating old code and this part does not work :

```dart
IFrameElement iframe = query('#myframe iframe');
Window iframeW = iframe.contentWindow;// cast error
var myframeDoc = iframeW.document;
```

I changed `Window` to 'WindowBase` :

```dart
IFrameElement iframe = query('#myframe iframe');
WindowBase iframeW = iframe.contentWindow;
var myframeDoc = iframeW.document;
```

But `document` is not a member of `WindowBase`.
I want to access it to query like this:

```dart
    myframeDoc.query("#myId");
```

With javascript, the solution works :

```javascript
var myframeDoc = document.querySelector('#myframe iframe').contentWindow.document;
```

Answer (score 2):

iFrame's and Windows have slightly different APIs, so you have to use `WindowBase` rather than `Window`.

You can see that the type of `IFrameElement.contentWindow` is `WindowBase` in the API docs and you should also see it in the pop-up docs in the Editor.

Comment: Indeed. I'am updating old code and I found a Breaking change about his. My new problem is __document__ is not a member of __WindowBase__.
My need is to query on the dom like this : __myframeDoc.query("myid")__

Comment: Great question then. You might want to update this question to make it clear that WindowBase lacks a document getter, and it's definitely worth a bug report.